# start /usr/bin/mysqld_safe in backgroud

Tags: mysql, docker, containers

i´m running a container with docker and mysql. My image base is Ubuntu 16, the problem is when i execute `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables` my terminal  stays in black and i can´t type or do anithing inside. Is there a way to execute this command and send the proceess to background? this container needs to execute commands and at the same time runing mysql in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `&` at the end of the line and it will go to the background.

Answer (score 1):

## Manual

Start docker container daemonized
`docker run -d --name mysql <image> -- /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables`

Connect to container and run commands:
`docker exec -it mysql sh`

### Entrypoint

Common approach is to use an entrypoint script.

```
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables &
# more commands etc.
```

set script as executable

`chmod 755 entrypoint.sh`

Then in your Dockerfile:
`ADD entrypoint.sh .`
`ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: thx bro, i just needed to put "&" at the end, anyway ill try to do it with a bash and see what happens